# VHDL program that chooses which operation to perform

Tags: vhdl, alu

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.numeric_bit.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity multiplexer is
port (
    A,B: in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    CI: in std_logic;
    CO: out std_logic;
    ANS: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    OP: in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    EN: in std_logic);
end multiplexer;

architecture archi of multiplexer is 
    signal tmp: std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);
begin
    process (EN) begin
        if (EN = '1') Then
            case OP is
            when "00" =>
                tmp <= conv_std_logic_vector((conv_integer(A)+conv_integer(B)+conv_integer(CI)),9);
                ANS<= tmp(7 downto 0);
                CO <= tmp(8);
            when "01" =>
                tmp <= conv_std_logic_vector((conv_integer(A)-conv_integer(B)+conv_integer(CI)),9);
                ANS<= tmp(7 downto 0);
                CO <= tmp(8);
            when others => NULL;

            end case;
        else
            NULL;
        end if;
    end process;
end archi;
```

error is coming at line 19 No feasible entries for infix operator '=' also Type error resolving infix expression "=" as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN. Where am I going wrong?
[wave output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WKmO.jpg)

Comment: Never use `std_logic_arith`, `std_logic_signed`, and `std_logic_unsigned`. This packages are not in standard. You can do everything you need with `numeric_std`. Besides, your code will not work, because inputs are not in the sensitivity list. And actually, I would do it with clock, to avoid hazards, and to be sure, that result is in proper time. But I'm not sure if it is necessary.

Comment: when i removed the std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned and added the numeric_std.all, there were lots of errors. Most of them were concentrated around the conv_integer part of the function tmp. Also after adjusting the code , as I had made an error, in declaration of EN the program compiled and ran successfully, But there were no values in ANS and CO, they were shown as UUU ,the value was only there in tmp?. Please see the wave output I uploaded. Where am I going wrong. Please help.

Comment: Well... simple. Stop using everything that comes from those libraries. Including conv_integer. Find numeric_std equivalent. For example instead of conv_integer use to_integer. As for issue with UUU in tmp - ask another question with improved code, without not standard libraries, this is longer story.

Answer (score 2):

Surely this:

```
EN: in std_logic_vector
```

should be this:

```
EN: in std_logic
```

Your error message is complaining that there is no `"="` operator defined that can compare a `std_logic_vector` to a `'1'`, which is a literal of type `std_logic`.

Comment: thanks a lot. I corrected that and the program compiled successfully, but , the wave output is showing that tmp is having a value but there is no value in ANS or CO? its being shown as UUUUUUUU

Comment: when I am adding 00000001(A) with 11111111(B) the value in tmp is showing 100000000 but there is no value in ANS or CO they are being shown as U ? Please help?

Comment: AS @Staszek says: you need to ask a new question. The idea of Stack Overflow is so that future users with the same problem can search for a specific answer to that specific problem. A future user can search for the same error message and perhaps this question and answer will help them. Now you have a new question; please ask a new question.